# Regular expression to search for an exact word

Tags: javascript, regex

Regular expression to search a particular word

i have following data

```
  (Calabash::Cucumber::Launcher::StartError)
 /Users/ushusadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.169/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:441:in `new_run_loop'
 /Users/ushusadmin/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/gems/calabash-cucumber-0.9.169/lib/calabash-cucumber/launcher.rb:351:in `relaunch'
 /Users/ushusadmin/Neema/mobile_cards_app/MobileCards/features/support/01_launch.rb:64:in `Before'
```

Using regular expression i want to search a word(StartError) is found or not..

Comment: Did you try anything? This does not need a regular expression as you're not searching for a pattern. You're searching for an exact string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression.

```
if (dataString.contains("StartError")) doSomething();
```

In response to your comment - sorry, I thought I saw a Java tag on this  question. You don't need a regex in javascript either:

```
if (dataString.indexOf("StartError") >= 0) doSomething();
```

[`String.prototype.indexOf(stringToMatch)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) returns either the index of (the first character in) the substring you're searching for , or -1 if it is not found. So a return value `>= 0` is no different than a return value of `true` from the java method above.

Comment: but am using nodejs and getting error has no method contains